# In App purchase. Product id sent but not able to receive

Tags: ios, ios7, in-app-purchase, unity-game-engine

While running the project it says
ProductsRequest sent with productIdentifiers: gives the list of product ids

But while receiving product ids it says invalid productIdentifier.

When i checked in app purchases for my app in the iTunes store in the status column it says waiting for review.

Does this has to do with invalid productIdentifier?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sandbox mode it should work even withing that state. If you are testing live version - than you will get such behavior until it's reviewed.

Comment: i want to test in the sandbox mode only but i am not able to reach there. Whenever i click on my in app purchase i get a message 'invalid productIdentifier'.

Comment: Hers is the code i am using

`void Start()
{
var productIdentifiers = new string[] {"product.100"};
StoreKitBinding.requestProductData( productIdentifiers );
}

void ButtonOne
{
bool canMakePayments = StoreKitBinding.canMakePayments();
StoreKitBinding.purchaseProduct( "product.100" , 1 );
}`